# Calculating a diminishing value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a value and total and a diminishing %:

- Value  = 100
- Total = 5
- Diminishing = 0.98 (98%)

Basically I want the sum of the Value diminishing up to the Total. So, using the above example, that's 5 lots of 100, diminished to 98% for each iteration:

i.e.
100 + 98 + 96.04 + 94.1192‬ + 92.236816 = Result

How can I achieve the Result in Excel?

Comment: Is it always going to be 5 times or is it going to be a different number?

Comment: Each variable will be different. 5 was an example, but in my graphs it needs to go as high as at least 1,000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FV:

```
=B1+SUM(FV(B3-1,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B2-1)),0,-B1))
```

Depending on one's version the formula may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Quick follow up, is there a way to have a minimum for the diminished value? For instance if the diminished value becomes less than 1, it would use 1?

Comment: Wrap the FV part with `MAX(...,1)` where the `...` is the FV part of the formula.

Comment: I did try that (MAX(20, FV($B$8-1,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,MAX(($B$7*A13)-$B$3,0))),0,-$B$1)))
It seems like it only returns 1 cell at that point, the first one. That may be my mistake in communication there. I mean the interest, as it were, needs an absolute minimum to apply each time. I'm guessing I need to edit the array of cells with a minimum after the FV

Comment: `=B1+SUM(MAX(1,FV(B3-1,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B2-1)),0,-B1)))` What is `MAX(($B$7*A13)-$B$3,0)` part for?

Comment: Apologies. The full line right now is: SUM(FV($B$8-1,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,MAX(($B$7*A13)-$B$3,0))),0,-$B$1))

The other MAX is just because there is a point in the total that need the diminishing returns. i.e. the first 100 values do not suffer diminished returns. So it ignores those.

But if I add MAX(1,FV(...)) I get 149.25 and no other values. This is the value of my first cell (150 * 0.995). So I think the MAX is returning the max of all cells, not maxing each individual cell? Basically if the min was 1 the cells would ideally be 2,1.5,1,1,1,1,1,etc

Comment: @user1539405 yup You are correct.  Ask another question showing what you have tried and let's see what the community thinks.

Comment: It was getting a bit convoluted down here wasn't it? Thanks a lot so far though, you've been a big help :)

Answer (score 0):

If we take starting amount as A, Rate of deduction as r % ( in decimal form  so for 2% we enter 0.02 ), and Iterations = N then final amount X can be given by a simple formula as :

X=A*(1-r)^(N-1)

So in First Row Give Titles to Columns as :

"Amount", "Percent r ", " N ", " Final ".

Accordingly enter data in Second row in Cell A2=100, B2=0.02, C2=5

Enter the formula in D2 as =A2*(1-B2)^(C2-1)

The result is 92.23682.

Copy the formula of D2, down the rows....

Now if you enter in third row data as : 1000, 0.04, 8

Then you get the final result in D3 as 751.44747811

So it becomes flexible for any type of data.

If the compounding is to increase then for r=.02, the change would 1+.02

So the Compounding Plus formula would be

X=A*(1+r)^(N-1).

Thanks.

Comment: In this case when iteration is 5 it, first year is 0, so for 5 iterations what we get is a beginning amount at 5th year. So I had to make the factor (N-1).

Comment: But in our Country we understand at the end of the 5th year. Therefore in our case we follow the formula as X=A*(1-r)^N and not N-1.

Comment: SO if we want final amount of money we get for a deposit of 5 Years, compounded annually say Rs. 12500 kept for 5 year at the rate of interest 12 % then final amount at the end of 5 years = 12500*(1+0.12)^5 =22029.27

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the problem. Your formula computes the last value in the series. For the OP’s data, that is 92.236816 (100×0.98⁴). But the OP wants the sum of all the values in the series, which is 480.396.

Answer (score 0):

Excel’s `FV` (future value) function appears to be the best tool to use
if you’re already using Excel. 
But the problem is easy to solve with a calculator if you do some math.

Let’s give the parameters names:

- V = 1000 (base value)
- N = 5   (number)
- d = 0.98  (diminishing/depreciation rate)

So the desired result (R) is

R = V + V×d + V×d<sup>2</sup> + V×d<sup>3</sup> + V×d<sup>4</sup>
  = V × (1 + d +d<sup>2</sup> +d<sup>3</sup> +d<sup>4</sup>)

The key to simplifying this is to look at the infinite series sum:

S = 1 + d + d<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>3</sup> + d<sup>4</sup> + d<sup>5</sup> + d <sup>6</sup> + d<sup>7</sup> + …

Now do some multiplication:

d × S  = d + d<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>3</sup> + d<sup>4</sup> + d<sup>5</sup> + d<sup>6</sup> + d<sup>7</sup> + d<sup>8</sup> + …
d<sup>5</sup>×S = d<sup>5</sup> + d<sup>6</sup> + d<sup>7</sup> + d<sup>8</sup> + d<sup>9</sup> + d<sup>10</sup> + …

Since these are *infinite* series, we can shift the placement of the terms:

d ×S  =   d + d<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>3</sup> + d<sup>4</sup> + d<sup>5</sup> + d<sup>6</sup> + d<sup>7</sup> + …
d<sup>5</sup>×S =           d<sup>5</sup> + d<sup>6</sup> + d<sup>7</sup> + …

Then we do some subtraction:

S = 1 + d + d<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>3</sup> + d<sup>4</sup> + d<sup>5</sup> + d<sup>6</sup> + d<sup>7</sup> + …
  −
    d ×S =  d + d<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>3</sup> + d<sup>4</sup> + d<sup>5</sup> + d<sup>6</sup> + d<sup>7</sup> + …
____________________________________________
 S   −    d  ×S = 1
  (1 – d)   ×   S = 1

… and solve for S:

S = 1 / (1 – d)

And do the same thing with N:

S = 1 + d + d<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>3</sup> + d<sup>4</sup> + d<sup>5</sup> + d<sup>6</sup> + d<sup>7</sup> + …
 −
   d<sup>5</sup>×S =          d<sup>5</sup> + d<sup>6</sup> + d<sup>7</sup> + …
____________________________________________
 S  −  d<sup>5</sup>×S = 1 + d + d<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>3</sup> + d<sup>4</sup>

Flipping sides:

1 + d + d<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>3</sup> + d<sup>4</sup> = S  −  d<sup>5</sup> × S
                = (1 – d<sup>5</sup>) × S
                = (1 – d<sup>5</sup>) × (1 / (1 – d))
                = (1 – d<sup>5</sup>) / (1 – d)

So

R = V × (1 – d<sup>N</sup>) / (1 – d)

You can do this in Excel with `=A1*(1-B1^C1)/(1-B1)`:

[image: simple spreadsheet showing the above formula with the OP's values]

Doing it in other tools/calculators is left as an exercise.

You can see a cleaner version of the above math [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR281.png).

Comment: Been a while since I revisited this question. But thank you Scott, that's a very informative answer and pretty light too! I've already marked the above as the answer, but I certainly consider this to be one too (wish I could mark both)