Creating a diminishing value math formula in Excel?
Consider the following example:
One (1) farm has the production value of 1. But for each 10 farms, the production is reduced by half. So what is the production value for 30 farms?
Calculating manually is quite straight forward;
For the first 10 farms    -> 10  production
For the second 10 farms   -> 10 * 0.5  = 5   production
And for the last 10 farms -> 10 * 0.25  = 2.5 production
Result: 17.5 production
But creating a formula isn't so trivial;
Searching for similar problems, I found this excellent post by the user Scott: https://superuser.com/a/1527430/2156837
Using his formula: R = V * (1 – d^N) / (1 – d)
Where V is the base value, d is the diminishing rate, and N the number of interactions.
The only detail, from my previous example, is that I don't have the number of interactions. But it can be easily calculated by dividing the total (30) by the base number (10).
So it goes like this:
R = 10 * (1 - 0.5^(30/10)) / (1 - 0.5)
R = 17.5
It works! But there is just one problem:
Assume the same example, but for 35 farms instead.
For the first 10 farms        -> 10  production
For the second 10 farms       -> 10 * 0.5   = 5   production
The following  10 farms       -> 10 * 0.25  = 2.5 production
And for the remaining 5 farms ->  5 * 0.125 = 0.625 production
Result: 18.125
By using the formula:
R = 10 * (1 - 0.5^(35/10)) / (1 - 0.5)
R = 18.23223305
Conclusion: the formula does not work if the number of interactions (N) is not an integer.
Can any math magicians tell me what went wrong or how to fix it?

Divide it into two formulas that you sum: =10*(1-0.5^(QUOTIENT(A1,10)))/(1-0.5)+MOD(A1,10)*((0.5^(QUOTIENT(A1,10))))

=10*(1-0.5^INT(A1/10))/0.5+MOD(A1,10)*0.5^INT(A1/10)

Or even =LET(x,0.5^INT(A1/10),10*(1-x)/0.5+MOD(A1,10)*x)

To respond to "what went wrong": I'm not sure of terminology, but I believe your actual problem is a step function whereas the formula is an approximation of the step function (i.e. a smooth curve). If you plot  your problem definition vs the formula you should be able to visualize what I am saying.

Dividing into two formulas did the trick. Thank you guys. I understand now. But how do I mark the answer? There is no checkmark on the left. I can't even upvote.

The above are all comments and not answers. I have made an answer of my comment

Divide it into two formulas that you sum:
=10*(1-0.5^(QUOTIENT(A1,10)))/(1-0.5)+MOD(A1,10)*((0.5^(QUOTIENT(A1,10))))

The first half of the formula calculates the total production for complete steps, the second one does the same, but for the last, partially completed step of the function.
